# How can I work with a .csv file using Java Spring Resttample?

Tags: java, spring, csv, resttemplate

I have a small problem concerning using a .csv file with the Resttemplate from java spring.
It looks somehow like:

```
URL url = URL url = new URL("http://data.wien.gv.at/daten/geo?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=ogdwien:GEONAMENSVERZOGD&outputFormat=CSV");
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
```

Late on I want to use the    getForObject() Method by the restTemplate, but I down't know how to proceed since I can't find matching paramteres anywehere on the internet.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you'll need a CSV parsing library such as SuperCSV or OpenCSV.

Second you can add a HttpMessageConverter to Spring to convert csv input to java objects.
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/HttpMessageConverter.html

Having that set up, you'll be able to getForObject and get java objects directly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'm already using a CSV Parsing library. My Problem is that I don't know what values I should enter using the method .getForObject(url,???); and how to proceed to get it into the csvParser. That's my problem.

Comment: The second parameter is the java type that you want the content to be converted to. I suppose you have a bean class defined that can be built from a CSV row, then the second parameter can be an array of that type .class i.e. MyCsvRow[].class
However, to do this you need to instruct Spring how to convert it using the HttpMessageConverter I was mentioning. 
Or you can simply get the content as String:
ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.getForObject(url, String.class);
and then pass it to your CSV parsing lib.

Comment: using  String response = restTemplate.getForObject(url, String.class); gets me an error, but don't know why. Would like to pass the response String to the CSV Parser, but no luck.